# Is there any way to use elastic IP with elastic beanstalk?

Tags: dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare

So i have a senario, where i have an application which can be assigned to any client's domain without doing anything on the application side. Client just adds the Cnames (the long url that is assigned to every Beanstalk app) of the Elastic Beanstalk URL.

So when client goes to www.example1.com they will see the website, similarly when another client goes to www.example2.com they will also see the same website. Now the issue is that i use clean url's without the www. In order to do that i have to Use A records, but Godaddy only let A records to be assigned to IP addresses but in the case of AWS beanstalk. I know you cant assign IP addresses to the Application url as the instances get deleted when scaled, so is there any other solution to this problem?

I have read somewhere that **cloudflare** can help but have no idea how to use it.

Well i know the question is not related to programming but i can see many similar questions asked over here, so i guess it should be OK.

**As always, any help is appreciated. Thankyou :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hosted zone "example1.com." in route53 and create an alias record "example1.com" pointing to the ELB of your environment in this hosted zone.

Now you can give the name servers for your route53 hosted zone to GoDaddy. Let me know if this setup does not work for you.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. lets say i have the official website as example1.com and other clients want to have the same website but with their own domain ie example2.com. So if i am using route53, will i have to add the domain example2.com manually in route53? Is it possible that i can just give them the nameservers and they can add these nameservers in their godaddy account, avoiding to manually add the domains in route 53?

Comment: See updated answer, I forgot you cannot create hosted zone with name "com.". But you can create hosted zone with name "example1.com." with alias record "example1.com." pointing to the ELB of your environment. You will need to give these name servers to GoDaddy. You can programmatically create a hosted zone for each client and give the nameservers for each new hosted zone to your client who can then provide it to GoDaddy. Apart from a script, I can't think of an automated way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Route53 with ALIAS.

You can do something manually, but the changes won't be permanent. See here for the full list of options: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-general